# azure logic app not able to retrieve who is the approver after approving the mail(UserEmailAddress- showing Null)

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have created a flow using logic apps where once the owner approves the mail I need to know who approved that mail. While using normal my account I am able to retrieve the user who approved the mail but while using the service account am not able to retrieve the values. All the values its showing as null while using the service account.
How do I get the --> email address <-- of the user that selects 'Approve' or 'Reject' buttons in the email? If an email is forwarded to another person I would like to know who (email address) clicked approve or reject.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I observed that when the mail is viewed in HTML format this doesn't work and also while forwarding the mail, but this works when the response is sent through the adaptive cards and not the HTML message that are received during the `Send email with options` action. One way that this can work is when you use only the adaptive cards that are send as the request.

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]

and when you use HTML responses then below is something how you'll be receiving the response.

[image]

You can also try [Creating your own actionable messages for Flow Approvals by StefanS365](https://2die4it.com/2019/04/15/create-your-own-actionable-messages-for-flow-approvals/) where in you add provider in Actionable Email Developer Dashboard and request the approvals.